# How can I `return` from inside of a call to `use`?

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin, this code compiles:

```
private fun bar(): Boolean = TODO()

fun works(): Int {
    while (true) {
        if (bar()) {
            return 5
        }
    }
}
```

(This is a pared down example of my real code to illustrate the issue I'm running into.)

I actually need to use a file during this loop, and close on exit:

```
fun openFile(): InputStream = TODO()

fun doesnt_work(): Int {
    openFile().use { input ->
        while (true) {
            if (bar()) {
                return 5
            }
        }
    }
 } // line 42
```

This doesn't compile. I get the error:

> Error:(42, 5) Kotlin: A 'return' expression required in a function with a block body ('{...}')

I've found two ways to work around this, but both are kind of awkward.

One way is to use a variable to hold the result, and break from the loop right when it's set:

```
fun works_but_awkward(): Int {
    openFile().use { input ->
        val result: Int
        while (true) {
            if (bar()) {
                result = 5
                break
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

This is especially awkward in my real code, as I have a nested loop, and so I need to use a labelled break.

The other way to work around this is to have a named function for the loop:

```
fun workaround_with_named_function(): Int {
    fun loop(input: InputStream): Int {
        while (true) {
            if (bar()) {
                return 5
            }
        }
    }
    return openFile().use { loop(it) }
}
```

This seems a bit better, but I'm still surprised that the `use` abstraction is so leaky that I can't do an early return from within a loop. Is there a way to use `use` with an early return in a loop that's less awkward?

Comment: The compiler can be pleased in your first doesnt_work() example if you return a dummy value after the use block, even if it will never be returned.  I suggest bringing this up at https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/ so the folks working on the language/library will hopefully see it or provide a better answer.

Comment: Please take a look at my answer, I think it looks better than both of your workaround and the other answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cause Kotlin compiler isn't smart enough to undestand that `use` with code inside will return something from the function. The reason of such behavior is inability to guarantee compiler that lambda will be called exactly once.

Another way to workaround this is throwing exception in the end of the function:

```
fun doesnt_work(): Int {
    openFile().use { input ->
        while (true) {
            if (bar()) {
                return 5
            }
        }
    }
    throw IllegalStateException("Something goes wrong")
}
```

**P.S.** I am not sure, but seems it can be compiled without any hacks when [contract system](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/status-of-kotlin-internal-contracts/6392) will be added to Kotlin. And it is probably going to be in version 1.3

Comment: I'd argue that an `AssertionError` is the right thing to throw there, since it should never happen.

Answer (score 2):

This should work.

```
fun openFile(): InputStream = TODO()

fun doesnt_work(): Int {
    return openFile().use { input ->
        while (true) {
            if (bar()) {
                return@use 5
            }
        }
        -1 // unreachable return value
           // just to help Kotlin infer the return type
    }
 }
```

Remember, `use` is a function whose return value is exactly the same with the return value of the lambda. So returning the value (here it's `5`) in the lambda and return the return value of `use` should work.

Also, if I were you, I'll write the function like this:

```
fun doesnt_work() = openFile().use { input ->
    while (true) if (bar()) return@use 5
    -1
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I get `Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: inferred type is Any but Int was expected` on `use`, and `Type mismatch: inferred type is Unit but Int was expected` on `while`. I'm using kotlinc-jvm 1.2.31.

Comment: Adding an unreachable final return statement will work, see my update. Sorry for not testing the code

Comment: @LaurenceGonsalves Hi, can you take a look at my edit?